# What is the probability ( represented as a decimal)that "A" , "B" and "C" will be printed?

Tags: python, random, probability

```
import random
y=random.randint(1,10)
if y>=1 and y<3:
    print ("A")
elif y>=3 and y<=7:
    print ("B")
else:
    print("C")
```

Comment: This seems like a math problem, not a programming question.

Comment: Python is case-sensitive: `Import` should be `import`, `Print` should be `print`. You're also missing the `:` on the `elif` line.

Comment: A 20%, B is 50% C is 30%. Take your RANGE/10. Mutliply the answer by 10 if you need to. That will give your percentage. Basic math.

Comment: Did you make any attempt to solve this yourself?

Answer (score 1):

You should really be able to figure it out yourself, but here I go:

randint returns an integer 1 to 10 (both included) so

- A: 2/10
- B: 5/10
- C: 3/10

Answer (score -1):

Without more context I would say

- A: 20% (Number 1 and 2)
- B: 50% (Number 3 - 7)
- C: 30% (Number 8 - 10

Answer (score -2):

If you just want to find whether it's A, B, or C, why not put the letters in a list and randomly pick one?

```
import random
x = ['A', 'B', 'C']

random.choice(x)
```

Comment: This will select them with equal probability. They want to know what the probabilities will be with the given random numbers.